# Android Studio Java errors but application is running

Tags: java, android, android-studio, syntax-error, content-assist

Dependencies

[image: Dependencies]

[image: Dependencies]

Import Errors

[image: Error in Imports]

Object and method errors

[image: Errors in methods]

I have created a new Application Project using Android Studio, and it is showing **errors in all java classes and functions**. But there is no error while building the project and running it on device.

It has been working perfectly for me but errors make it difficult to debug the code. Just because of this content assist is also not working properly.

*P.S. No issues with XML files.*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/usziQ.jpg

Comment: You don't have support library. Check your SDK manager. And please switch to Android Studio

Comment: Already Using Android Studio

Comment: and I have support library with version 22.2

Comment: you are doing gradle build at that time?

Comment: I am new to Android Studio, I am only press Run 'app' button

Comment: Forgot to see the image i have attatched with the question...?